# How to add a List of Items to a multi-column DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my program, I store the input from two TextBox Controls in two separate lists which I will use to populate a DataGridView.

I haven't actually added any code yet except for storing textbox values in the lists:

```
List<string> lTypes = new List<string>();
List<int> lAmounts = new List<int>();

private void btnAddItemL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lTypes.Add(txtItemL.Text);
    lAmounts.Add(int.Parse(txtAmountL.Text));
}
```

I have two separate columns as "Type" (filled by `lTypes`) and "Amount" (filled by `lAmounts`).

How do I make the lists populate their respective columns separately?

Comment: The two lists shown do not hold objects, just strings and integers, so it is unclear if that is the 'list of objects' mentioned in the title.  There are oodles of posts here covering basic databinding though.  Also, take care of the tags used - your question has nothing to do with Visual Studio

Comment: Don't use two `List<T>` collection, use a `BindingList<class>`. Build a class object that can store the data types you're planning to work with. If other Controls, besides the DataGridView, need to bind to the data, set the BindingList as the DataSource of a BindingSource and use the latter as the DataSource of the DGV and the source of the DataBindings of other Controls (those that don't have a DataSource).

Comment: @Jimi Could you show me the code as an answer to the question? (I'm new to the programming field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description,you want to add list items to a multi-Column dataGridView.

You can try the following code to solve this problem.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Create a Commodity class, including lType, lAmount properties
        public class Commodity 
        {
            public string lType { get; set; }
            public int lAmount { get; set; }           
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        
        List<Commodity> list = new List<Commodity>();//Create a List<Commodity> collection
        private void btnAddItemL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Commodity co = new Commodity(); //Create an object of type Commodity
            co.lType = txtItemL.Text; //Assign values to the property of the object
            co.lAmount = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmountL.Text);
            list.Add(co);//Add the object to list
            /* When the data source of the DataGridview is the list, the data will not be updated when the list is operated and then bound. Using BindingList can solve this problem well.*/
            var bindingList = new BindingList<Commodity>(list);   //List<T> is converted to BindingList<T>
            var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);    //Create a data source of type BindingSource with the specified BindingList<T>            
            dataGridView1.DataSource = source;//bind your dataGridView to the BindingSource   

        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is what I need. If you don't mind, could you explain the function of the button code line by line? This is for my Diploma project and in our presentation they might ask for the code's functions.

Comment: And is it possible to use this list combined with a TSQL statement to change a database table?

Comment: @ZaidHussain, I have added the related comment in the code. I suggest that your TSQL problem can be reposted in a new post, which will enable you to get more help faster.

Answer (score 1):

A possible scenario:

- Two TextBox Controls use to input some data, a `string` value and an `int` value.
- The data should be stored and shown in a DataGridView.

  - It's not clear whether other Controls are involved, share the same data or can modify it: let's assume that some other Control might be willing to participate, now or in the future.
- The data might need to be serialized at some point, or stored permanently.
- The data could be also presented in a different User Interface.

Now, you're using two `List<T>` as storage (where `T` is `string` in one case and `int` in another), to then show the content of the lists in a DataGridView, of course in two distinct columns.

This setup does not exactly meet the requirements: a DataGridView is better served by an *homogeneous* data source, organized in Columns and Rows.

► It's of course to note that we can enter and edit data using the DataGridView Control itself. Sometimes it's practical, sometimes it's not. To evaluate. In any case, the collection of objects used as DataSource needs to support it.

We can build a class object to store the data, using properties that match the data type needed.
Also, when dealing with UI presentation of data, it's quite better to use the DataBinding features that the Framework offers: it makes everything more *linear*.

In WinForms, the [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1) and [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) objects offer a lot of feature out of the box, as data and databindings change events, automatic currency management etc., that allow to synchronize all UI elements that need to share a source of data.

We just need to build an object that can describe our data, generate a List of these data object (using a BindingList) and bind all UI elements to the List using a BindingSource. The BindingSource can be used as source of data for both Control that expose a [DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ilistsource) property (as the DataGridView) and Controls that use [DataBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.databindings).

**Base unit object**:

```
public class StorageObject
{
    public StorageObject() { }
    public StorageObject(string type, int amount)
    {
        this.StorageType = type;
        this.Amount = amount;
    }

    public string StorageType { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Let's build a *Manager* object that expose the entities that we need to setup the DataBindings:

- This class object handles a `BindingList<StorageObject>` and a BindingSource, linked to the BindingList, that provides the data binding our Controls need to share and present the data, plus add new object or edit/update the existing.
- The class also expose a couple of methods that allow to add or remove data units from the data source in a *controlled* manner (here, simplified to demonstrate the feature).

The `MyStorage` class provides a layer between the storage unit and the UI elements that need to use the data that each unit holds.

Using this class object, we can setup the data bindings we need:

- Set the DataSource of a DataGridView to the BindingSource.
- Create two Bindings to bind two TextBox Controls to the same source (those you see on the right side, inside the `Current` Panel, in the animation).
- Add two more (unbound) TextBox controls to input data (those you see at the bottom in the animation).

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
    private MyStorage myStorage = null;

    public SomeForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        myStorage = new MyStorage();

        myDataGridView.DataSource = myStorage.StorageSource; 
        txtCurrentType.DataBindings.Add("Text", myStorage.StorageSource, "StorageType", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        txtCurrentAmount.DataBindings.Add("Text", myStorage.StorageSource, "Amount", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
}
```

To add a `StorageObject` manually to the collection of objects, using a Button as shown in the visual sample (in the animation, **`txtType`** and **`txtAmount`** are the two TextBox Controls at the bottom, near the **`Add...`** Button):

```
private void btnAddStorageObject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, out int amount) && txtType.TextLength > 0) {
        myStorage.Add(txtType.Text, amount);
    }
}
```

To remove an object from the collection, using a Button:

```
private void btnRemoveCurrent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove the object that is Current in the BindingSource
    myStorage.Remove(myStorage.StorageSource.Current as StorageObject);

    // Or, pick one or the other
    if (int.TryParse(txtCurrentAmount.Text, out int amount)) {
       myStorage.Remove(txtCurrentType.Text, amount);
    }
}
```

You can pass the **`MyStorage`** object to another Form and present, edit or otherwise use the data it points to in any way that makes sense in that context:
(**`InputDialog`** is a Form, as shown in the visual example. Add a Constructor to the Form that accepts a `BindingSource` as argument)

```
private void btnUseDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var inputDialog = new InputDialog(myStorage.StorageSource);
    inputDialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

That's all. If we need to bind other Controls, we just use the **`myStorage.StorageSource`** (the BindingSource). We can also pass this object reference to other classes (a Form is also a class).

**Visual samples of the operations described**:

[image: WinForms DataBindings]

**The `MyStorage` *Data Manager* class object**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

public class MyStorage
{
    private BindingList<StorageObject> m_Storage = null;

    public MyStorage() : this(null) { }
    public MyStorage(IList<StorageObject> list) {
        this.m_Storage = list != null 
            ? new BindingList<StorageObject>(list)
            : new BindingList<StorageObject>();

        this.StorageSource = new BindingSource(this.m_Storage, null);
    }

    public BindingSource StorageSource { get; }
    public IList<StorageObject> Storage => m_Storage.ToList();

    public StorageObject Add(string type, int amount)
    {
        var obj = new StorageObject(type, amount);
        m_Storage.Add(obj);
        return obj;
    }

    public bool Remove(string type, int amount)
    {
        if (m_Storage.Count == 0) return false;
        var obj = m_Storage.FirstOrDefault(st => st.StorageType.Equals(type) && st.Amount == amount);
        return Remove(obj);
    }

    public bool Remove(StorageObject obj)
    {
        if (obj != null && m_Storage.Contains(obj)) {
            return m_Storage.Remove(obj);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My apologies, but this method is a little too complicated for me.

Comment: The methods shown here are quite similar to what is described in the answer you accepted, except, here, I'm using a reusable class object to handle the objects that provide the data and the data bindings (so you have everything in one place, as it should be). Maybe, in the future, get back to this and give it second look. You'll probably find out that, one day or another you have built or though about building something similar (or moved to a mini-ORM, like Dapper, or EntityFramework - btw, when you'll have to choose one, pick the former :)